# CopyToDataTable() for empty rows

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

The below code wth line CopyToDataTable() throws error when there there isn't any rows available, how to deal with it?

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetContestants() As String
    Dim dttemp As DataTable
    currentCount += pageSize
    dttemp = dtContestantList.Rows.Cast(Of System.Data.DataRow)().Skip(currentCount).Take(pageSize).CopyToDataTable()
    Return GetJson(dttemp)
End Function
```

Comment: This is not LINQ-to-SQL... But: what error? What does it say?

Comment: Btw, unrelated: but - this method suggests that dtContestantList is a static ("shared") DataTable - be very careful if you plan on making changes to tht DataTable - it is not thread safe

Comment: the error says: The source contains no DataRows.

Comment: That exception is documented: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to check that first:

```
Dim rows = dtContestantList.Rows.Cast(Of System.Data.DataRow)().Skip(currentCount).Take(pageSize)
If rows.Any() Then
    dttemp = rows.CopyToDataTable()
    Return GetJson(dttemp)
Else
    Return ""  
End If
```

Possible exceptions with [`CopytoDataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx)

- ArgumentNullException
  The source IEnumerable sequence is null and a new table cannot be created.
- InvalidOperationException

  - A DataRow in the source sequence has a state of Deleted.
  - **The source sequence does not contain any DataRow objects.**
  - A DataRow in the source sequence is null.

Note that you should be careful with shared/static `DataTables` in  ASP.NET which is a multi threading environment. It's not thread safe. You should use it only for lookups.